# Obtaining report results via REST

Tags: rest-api, reports-api

I was following this article to fetch data from reports using the query api, so that I can apply filter in the future: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_report_query_example.htm#sforce_analytics_rest_api_report_query_example

But after applying all parameters in a POST request body, I always get zero row count.

Request Uri : /services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/query

**Request body:**

```json
    {
       "reportMetadata":{
          "aggregates":[
             "RowCount"
          ],
          "id":"00O0m000000byouEAA",
          "name":"Large Report 02",
          "developerName":"Large_Report_02_W7Z",
          "chart":null,
          "crossFilters":[
             
          ],
          "currency":null,
          "description":null,
          "detailColumns":[
             "ACCOUNT.NAME"
          ],
          "reportBooleanFilter":null,
          "reportFilters":[
             
          ],
         "reportFormat":"TABULAR",
          "reportType":{
             "label":"Sites",
             "type":"AccountList"
          },
           "scope" : "organization",
        "showGrandTotal" : true,
        "showSubtotals" : true,
        "sortBy" : [ ]
       }
    }
```

**Response:**

```json
    {
        "attributes": {
            "describeUrl": "/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/null/describe",
            "instancesUrl": "/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/null/instances",
            "reportId": null,
            "reportName": "Large Report 02",
            "type": "Report"
        },
        "allData": true,
        "factMap": {
            "T!T": {
                "aggregates": [
                    {
                        "label": "0",
                        "value": 0
                    }
                ],
                "rows": []
            }
        },
        "groupingsAcross": {
            "groupings": []
        },
        "groupingsDown": {
            "groupings": []
        },
        "hasDetailRows": true,
        "reportExtendedMetadata": {
            "aggregateColumnInfo": {
                "RowCount": {
                    "dataType": "int",
                    "label": "Record Count"
                }
            },
            "detailColumnInfo": {
                "ACCOUNT.NAME": {
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "label": "Site Name"
                }
            },
            "groupingColumnInfo": {}
        },
        "reportMetadata": {
            "aggregates": [
                "RowCount"
            ],
            "chart": null,
            "crossFilters": [],
            "currency": null,
            "description": null,
            "detailColumns": [
                "ACCOUNT.NAME"
            ],
            "developerName": null,
            "division": null,
            "folderId": "0051K00000A1X3vQAF",
            "groupingsAcross": [],
            "groupingsDown": [],
            "hasDetailRows": true,
            "hasRecordCount": true,
            "historicalSnapshotDates": [],
            "id": null,
            "name": "Large Report 02",
            "reportBooleanFilter": null,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "reportFormat": "TABULAR",
            "reportType": {
                "label": "Sites",
                "type": "AccountList"
            },
            "scope": "organization",
            "showGrandTotal": true,
            "showSubtotals": true,
            "sortBy": [],
            "standardDateFilter": {
                "column": "CREATED_DATE",
                "durationValue": "CUSTOM",
                "endDate": null,
                "startDate": "2022-05-22"
            },
            "standardFilters": null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it showing Data when you run the report from from UI?

Comment: yes , even I can export data in excel from salesforce UI which has 2317 records